# programmatic ACL inheritance

Tags: .net, windows, acl

I'm written a (.net / c#) program creating folders with ACL:

```
ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.SetOwner(up.Sid);
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-551"), FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow)); // Backup operators                       
DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(path, ds);
```

So: User "up" gets full control and backup User read permission.

This is how it locks with "icacls":

```
C:\Windows>icacls \\testsrv16\Share\SecFold\data\
\\testsrv16\Share\SecFold\data\ VORDEFINIERT\Sicherungs-Operatoren:(OI)(IO)(R)
                                TEST\XXXUser:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

(XXXUser - the created user; Sicherungs-Operatoren: Backup user)

Created folder "y":

```
C:\Windows>icacls \\testsrv16\Share\SecFold\data\y
\\testsrv16\Share\SecFold\data\y VORDEFINIERT\Sicherungs-Operatoren:(OI)(IO)(R)
                                 TEST\XXXUser:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

So:
Every permission is copied, not inherited.

With [icacls "C:\demo\example" /inheritance:e /T](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) I can activate inheritance.

Why is this not standard? How to do this by program?

Comment: Rick Strahl figured out the [proper incantation](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Jan/04/Setting-ACEACL-permissions-in-NET-20).

Comment: Hello. The post from "Jerry Issa" is helpful, sadly this did not solve my problem :(